# Delete a mutex from another process

Tags: c#, mutex, instances, ntdll

Using the topic *[Overview - Handle Enumeration](http://forum.sysinternals.com/topic14546&OB=DESC_page2.html)*, number 5, the attempt *[Close mutex of another process](http://forum.sysinternals.com/close-mutex-of-another-process_topic15061_page1.html)* and and information from *[Mutex analysis, the canary in the coal mine and discovering new families of malware/](http://www.networkforensics.com/forensics-and-reverse-engineering-series/mutex-analysis-the-canary-in-the-coal-mine-and-discovering-new-families-of-malware/)*, I have came up with:

`Attempt 1:` http://pastebin.com/QU0WBgE5

You must open [Notepad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) first. Needless to say, this is not working for me. I need better error checking to figure out what's going on. I don't know how to get mutex pointers in the format I see them in [Process Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Explorer).

My goal is to be able to delete/kill of the mutex handles created by a process so more than one instance can be open. I can do this manually using Process Explorer, but I want to do it programmatically.

---

(Based on Yahia's notes, I need more permissions.)

`Attempt 2:` http://pastebin.com/yyQLhesP

At least now I have some sort of error checking, most of the time DuplicateHandle returns 6 or 5, which is an *invalid handle* and *access denied* respectfully.

---

Working attempt (kind of):

I actually didn't require anything Yahia stated in the end. I was getting a "local" handle when I needed a remote one. Basically, what I mean is that you have to find the HandleValue using `NtQuerySystemInformation` and use that handle, not the one returned by `OpenMutex` / `CreateMutex`.

Granted, I can't get it to work on some applications (osk.exe -- on screen keyboard), but it worked for the application I was going for, posting code in case someone wants to take it further.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Principal;
namespace FileLockInfo
{

    public class Win32API
    {
        [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
        public static extern int NtQueryObject(IntPtr ObjectHandle, int
            ObjectInformationClass, IntPtr ObjectInformation, int ObjectInformationLength,
            ref int returnLength);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern uint QueryDosDevice(string lpDeviceName, StringBuilder lpTargetPath, int ucchMax);

        [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
        public static extern uint NtQuerySystemInformation(int
            SystemInformationClass, IntPtr SystemInformation, int SystemInformationLength,
            ref int returnLength);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr OpenMutex(UInt32 desiredAccess, bool inheritHandle, string name);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags dwDesiredAccess, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern int CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool DuplicateHandle(IntPtr hSourceProcessHandle,
           ushort hSourceHandle, IntPtr hTargetProcessHandle, out IntPtr lpTargetHandle,
           uint dwDesiredAccess, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bInheritHandle, uint dwOptions);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

        public enum ObjectInformationClass : int
        {
            ObjectBasicInformation = 0,
            ObjectNameInformation = 1,
            ObjectTypeInformation = 2,
            ObjectAllTypesInformation = 3,
            ObjectHandleInformation = 4
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum ProcessAccessFlags : uint
        {
            All = 0x001F0FFF,
            Terminate = 0x00000001,
            CreateThread = 0x00000002,
            VMOperation = 0x00000008,
            VMRead = 0x00000010,
            VMWrite = 0x00000020,
            DupHandle = 0x00000040,
            SetInformation = 0x00000200,
            QueryInformation = 0x00000400,
            Synchronize = 0x00100000
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION
        { // Information Class 0
            public int Attributes;
            public int GrantedAccess;
            public int HandleCount;
            public int PointerCount;
            public int PagedPoolUsage;
            public int NonPagedPoolUsage;
            public int Reserved1;
            public int Reserved2;
            public int Reserved3;
            public int NameInformationLength;
            public int TypeInformationLength;
            public int SecurityDescriptorLength;
            public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME CreateTime;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION
        { // Information Class 2
            public UNICODE_STRING Name;
            public int ObjectCount;
            public int HandleCount;
            public int Reserved1;
            public int Reserved2;
            public int Reserved3;
            public int Reserved4;
            public int PeakObjectCount;
            public int PeakHandleCount;
            public int Reserved5;
            public int Reserved6;
            public int Reserved7;
            public int Reserved8;
            public int InvalidAttributes;
            public GENERIC_MAPPING GenericMapping;
            public int ValidAccess;
            public byte Unknown;
            public byte MaintainHandleDatabase;
            public int PoolType;
            public int PagedPoolUsage;
            public int NonPagedPoolUsage;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION
        { // Information Class 1
            public UNICODE_STRING Name;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
        public struct UNICODE_STRING
        {
            public ushort Length;
            public ushort MaximumLength;
            public IntPtr Buffer;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct GENERIC_MAPPING
        {
            public int GenericRead;
            public int GenericWrite;
            public int GenericExecute;
            public int GenericAll;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
        public struct SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION
        { // Information Class 16
            public int ProcessID;
            public byte ObjectTypeNumber;
            public byte Flags; // 0x01 = PROTECT_FROM_CLOSE, 0x02 = INHERIT
            public ushort Handle;
            public int Object_Pointer;
            public UInt32 GrantedAccess;
        }

        public const int MAX_PATH = 260;
        public const uint STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH = 0xC0000004;
        public const int DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS = 0x2;
        public const int DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE = 0x1;
    }

    public class Win32Processes
    {
        const int CNST_SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION = 16;
        const uint STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH = 0xc0000004;

        public static string getObjectTypeName(Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION shHandle, Process process)
        {
            IntPtr m_ipProcessHwnd = Win32API.OpenProcess(Win32API.ProcessAccessFlags.All, false, process.Id);
            IntPtr ipHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            var objBasic = new Win32API.OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION();
            IntPtr ipBasic = IntPtr.Zero;
            var objObjectType = new Win32API.OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION();
            IntPtr ipObjectType = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr ipObjectName = IntPtr.Zero;
            string strObjectTypeName = "";
            int nLength = 0;
            int nReturn = 0;
            IntPtr ipTemp = IntPtr.Zero;

            if (!Win32API.DuplicateHandle(m_ipProcessHwnd, shHandle.Handle,
                                          Win32API.GetCurrentProcess(), out ipHandle,
                                          0, false, Win32API.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS))
                return null;

            ipBasic = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(objBasic));
            Win32API.NtQueryObject(ipHandle, (int)Win32API.ObjectInformationClass.ObjectBasicInformation,
                                   ipBasic, Marshal.SizeOf(objBasic), ref nLength);
            objBasic = (Win32API.OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipBasic, objBasic.GetType());
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipBasic);

            ipObjectType = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(objBasic.TypeInformationLength);
            nLength = objBasic.TypeInformationLength;
            while ((uint)(nReturn = Win32API.NtQueryObject(
                ipHandle, (int)Win32API.ObjectInformationClass.ObjectTypeInformation, ipObjectType,
                  nLength, ref nLength)) ==
                Win32API.STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipObjectType);
                ipObjectType = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nLength);
            }

            objObjectType = (Win32API.OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipObjectType, objObjectType.GetType());
            if (Is64Bits())
            {
                ipTemp = new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt64(objObjectType.Name.Buffer.ToString(), 10) >> 32);
            }
            else
            {
                ipTemp = objObjectType.Name.Buffer;
            }

            strObjectTypeName = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ipTemp, objObjectType.Name.Length >> 1);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipObjectType);
            return strObjectTypeName;
        }


        public static string getObjectName(Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION shHandle, Process process)
        {
            IntPtr m_ipProcessHwnd = Win32API.OpenProcess(Win32API.ProcessAccessFlags.All, false, process.Id);
            IntPtr ipHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            var objBasic = new Win32API.OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION();
            IntPtr ipBasic = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr ipObjectType = IntPtr.Zero;
            var objObjectName = new Win32API.OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION();
            IntPtr ipObjectName = IntPtr.Zero;
            string strObjectName = "";
            int nLength = 0;
            int nReturn = 0;
            IntPtr ipTemp = IntPtr.Zero;

            if (!Win32API.DuplicateHandle(m_ipProcessHwnd, shHandle.Handle, Win32API.GetCurrentProcess(),
                                          out ipHandle, 0, false, Win32API.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS))
                return null;

            ipBasic = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(objBasic));
            Win32API.NtQueryObject(ipHandle, (int)Win32API.ObjectInformationClass.ObjectBasicInformation,
                                   ipBasic, Marshal.SizeOf(objBasic), ref nLength);
            objBasic = (Win32API.OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipBasic, objBasic.GetType());
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipBasic);


            nLength = objBasic.NameInformationLength;

            ipObjectName = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nLength);
            while ((uint)(nReturn = Win32API.NtQueryObject(
                     ipHandle, (int)Win32API.ObjectInformationClass.ObjectNameInformation,
                     ipObjectName, nLength, ref nLength))
                   == Win32API.STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipObjectName);
                ipObjectName = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nLength);
            }
            objObjectName = (Win32API.OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipObjectName, objObjectName.GetType());

            if (Is64Bits())
            {
                ipTemp = new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt64(objObjectName.Name.Buffer.ToString(), 10) >> 32);
            }
            else
            {
                ipTemp = objObjectName.Name.Buffer;
            }

            if (ipTemp != IntPtr.Zero)
            {

                byte[] baTemp2 = new byte[nLength];
                try
                {
                    Marshal.Copy(ipTemp, baTemp2, 0, nLength);

                    strObjectName = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(Is64Bits() ?
                                                           new IntPtr(ipTemp.ToInt64()) :
                                                           new IntPtr(ipTemp.ToInt32()));
                    return strObjectName;
                }
                catch (AccessViolationException)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                finally
                {
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipObjectName);
                    Win32API.CloseHandle(ipHandle);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public static List<Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION>
        GetHandles(Process process = null, string IN_strObjectTypeName = null, string IN_strObjectName = null)
        {
            uint nStatus;
            int nHandleInfoSize = 0x10000;
            IntPtr ipHandlePointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nHandleInfoSize);
            int nLength = 0;
            IntPtr ipHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

            while ((nStatus = Win32API.NtQuerySystemInformation(CNST_SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION, ipHandlePointer,
                                                                nHandleInfoSize, ref nLength)) ==
                    STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
            {
                nHandleInfoSize = nLength;
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipHandlePointer);
                ipHandlePointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nLength);
            }

            byte[] baTemp = new byte[nLength];
            Marshal.Copy(ipHandlePointer, baTemp, 0, nLength);

            long lHandleCount = 0;
            if (Is64Bits())
            {
                lHandleCount = Marshal.ReadInt64(ipHandlePointer);
                ipHandle = new IntPtr(ipHandlePointer.ToInt64() + 8);
            }
            else
            {
                lHandleCount = Marshal.ReadInt32(ipHandlePointer);
                ipHandle = new IntPtr(ipHandlePointer.ToInt32() + 4);
            }

            Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION shHandle;
            List<Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION> lstHandles = new List<Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION>();

            for (long lIndex = 0; lIndex < lHandleCount; lIndex++)
            {
                shHandle = new Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION();
                if (Is64Bits())
                {
                    shHandle = (Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipHandle, shHandle.GetType());
                    ipHandle = new IntPtr(ipHandle.ToInt64() + Marshal.SizeOf(shHandle) + 8);
                }
                else
                {
                    ipHandle = new IntPtr(ipHandle.ToInt64() + Marshal.SizeOf(shHandle));
                    shHandle = (Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipHandle, shHandle.GetType());
                }

                if (process != null)
                {
                    if (shHandle.ProcessID != process.Id) continue;
                }

                string strObjectTypeName = "";
                if (IN_strObjectTypeName != null){
                     strObjectTypeName = getObjectTypeName(shHandle, Process.GetProcessById(shHandle.ProcessID));
                    if (strObjectTypeName != IN_strObjectTypeName) continue;
                }

                string strObjectName = "";
                if (IN_strObjectName != null){
                     strObjectName = getObjectName(shHandle, Process.GetProcessById(shHandle.ProcessID));
                    if (strObjectName != IN_strObjectName) continue;
                }

                string strObjectTypeName2 = getObjectTypeName(shHandle, Process.GetProcessById(shHandle.ProcessID));
                string strObjectName2 = getObjectName(shHandle, Process.GetProcessById(shHandle.ProcessID));
                Console.WriteLine("{0}   {1}   {2}", shHandle.ProcessID, strObjectTypeName2, strObjectName2);

                lstHandles.Add(shHandle);
            }
            return lstHandles;
        }

        public static bool Is64Bits()
        {
            return Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)) == 8 ? true : false;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String MutexName = "MSCTF.Asm.MutexDefault1";
            String ProcessName = "notepad";

            try
            {
                Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcessName)[0];
                var handles = Win32Processes.GetHandles(process, "Mutant", "\\Sessions\\1\\BaseNamedObjects\\" + MutexName);
                if (handles.Count == 0) throw new System.ArgumentException("NoMutex", "original");
                foreach (var handle in handles)
                {
                    IntPtr ipHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
                    if (!Win32API.DuplicateHandle(Process.GetProcessById(handle.ProcessID).Handle, handle.Handle, Win32API.GetCurrentProcess(), out ipHandle, 0, false, Win32API.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE))
                        Console.WriteLine("DuplicateHandle() failed, error = {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                    Console.WriteLine("Mutex was killed");
                }
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The process name '{0}' is not currently running", ProcessName);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The Mutex '{0}' was not found in the process '{1}'", MutexName, ProcessName);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that the getObjectTypeName function (called 2x by the GetHandles function) utilizes the DuplicateHandle function to retrieve a copy of the original handle and find the object type name. You may need to utilize CloseHandle function on ipHandle if you are seeing unexpected copies of the original handle on the calling process.

Answer (score 0):

You need elevated privileges for that - especially DEBUG privilege.

See:

- *[Manipulate Privileges in Managed Code Reliably, Securely, and Efficiently](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163823.aspx)* (MSDN)
- *[Debug Privilege](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff541528%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)* (MSDN)
- *[The Windows Access Control Model Part 3](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/accessctrl3.aspx)*
- [Simon Mourier's answer to Stack Overflow question *How to enable the SeCreateGlobalPrivilege in .NET without resorting to P/Invoke or reflection?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528888/how-to-enable-the-secreateglobalprivilege-in-net-without-resorting-to-p-invoke-o/5535502#5535502)
- *[ObjectSecurity Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity_methods.aspx)*  (MSDN)

Comment: It certainly doesn't help you link me C++ examples for C# but after some googling I think I came to some ideas...though once I have the htoken for the process, how do I use it to obtain and modify the mutex? .. code: http://pastebin.com/F3W00gk0

Comment: if you check all the links there are C# examples too, not just C++ examples... esp. the last 3 examples... check them out, I think they can help