AdjustTokenPrivileges works in .NET Framework 4.6 but fails in .NET 8
I am encountering an issue where the AdjustTokenPrivileges function works perfectly in .NET Framework 4.6 but does not work in .NET 8.
Here's what happens:

In .NET Framework 4.6, the privilege adjustment succeeds, and I can
enable privileges such as SeDebugPrivilege.
In .NET 8, using the exact same code, the return value is 0, and the result of GetLastError() is Permission denied (I am running the process with Administrator).

The Code:
Here’s the code I am using:
 public static IntPtr GetCurrentProcessToken()
 {
     IntPtr tokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
     IntPtr currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle;

     if (!WinAPI.OpenProcessToken(currentProcess, WinAPI.TOKEN_QUERY, out tokenHandle))
         return IntPtr.Zero;

     return tokenHandle;
 }

public static bool SetDebugPrivilege()
{
    string Privilege = "SeDebugPrivilege";
    IntPtr hToken = GetCurrentProcessToken();
    if (hToken == IntPtr.Zero)
        return false;

    WinAPI.LUID luid = new();
    if (!WinAPI.LookupPrivilegeValue(null, Privilege, ref luid))
        return false;

    WinAPI.LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES luidAndAttributes = new WinAPI.LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES();
    luidAndAttributes.Luid = luid;
    luidAndAttributes.Attributes = WinAPI.SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED ;

    WinAPI.TOKEN_PRIVILEGES newState = new WinAPI.TOKEN_PRIVILEGES();
    newState.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    newState.Privileges = luidAndAttributes;

    WinAPI.TOKEN_PRIVILEGES previousState = new WinAPI.TOKEN_PRIVILEGES();
    UInt32 returnLength = 0;
    if (!WinAPI.AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, false, ref newState, (UInt32)Marshal.SizeOf(newState), ref previousState, out returnLength))
        return false;

    return true;
}

And structures in WinApi class:
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct LUID
{
    public UInt32 LowPart;
    public UInt32 HighPart;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES
{
    public LUID Luid;
    public UInt32 Attributes;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct TOKEN_PRIVILEGES
{
    public UInt32 PrivilegeCount;
    public LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES Privileges;
}

public const UInt32 SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED = 0x2;
public const uint TOKEN_QUERY = 0x0008;

[DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
public static extern bool LookupPrivilegeValue(string systemName, string privilegeName, ref LUID luid);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool AdjustTokenPrivileges(
    IntPtr TokenHandle,
    bool DisableAllPrivileges,
    ref TOKEN_PRIVILEGES NewState,
    uint BufferLength,
    ref TOKEN_PRIVILEGES PreviousState,
    out uint ReturnLength
);

I suspect that this might be related to changes in how the .NET runtime handles P/Invoke or marshaling in .NET 8. However, I have been unable to determine the root cause.
Additional Information:

WinAPI contains the necessary interop declarations.
I have verified that the token handle (hToken) is valid and that LookupPrivilegeValue succeeds in both versions.

My Question:

Are there any known changes in .NET 8 that could impact the behavior of AdjustTokenPrivileges?
Could this be an issue with P/Invoke changes in .NET 8, such as structure alignment or marshaling?
How can I troubleshoot this to make it work in .NET 8?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

When you say "fails silently" - you're calling a method that returns a Boolean value, but you appear not to be using the return value. Have you looked at what the return value is, and called GetLastError?

edited. @JonSkeet

Should work the same, but how do you declare all structures and API (dllimport, etc.)?

you should put everything in the question, not in comment, with all structures and functions

@SimonMourier edited.

We don't have enough code to reproduce, every detail matters

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.enterdebugmode?view=net-8.0

I'm surprised it even allows you to modify the privileges on the pseudo-token at all.

@SimonMourier I've added all the necessary details to the question now. Please take a look.

When run in an admin console, this code as is (with OpenProcessToken added since it's missing) reports error 5 in last error (Access Denied) from AdjustTokenPrivileges, in .NET Framework 4.6, 4.8 and in .NET 8 as expected. Whatever problem you have is probably unrelated to .NET version

@SimonMourier As I mentioned in my question, on my system, AdjustTokenPrivileges returns true with .NET Framework 4.6 and 4.8, but it fails with Access Denied in .NET 8. Now, since it doesn’t work on your system in both versions, could you suggest how we might use AdjustTokenPrivileges so that it would work universally?

You must include TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES when calling OpenProcessToken whatever language or framework your use.

Note this trick here should work for both .NET 4.X and .NET 5+ https://stackoverflow.com/a/5535502/403671 but for .NET 5+ you need to install this nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/system.security.accesscontrol which is not included by default
